# Running Single Flask Unittest Passes but Running All Tests Gives AssertionError

Tags: python, flask, nosetests, flask-restful

I have Flask application that uses the Flask-Restful library. I have a my app structure set up like so:

```
server
 application.py
- app
   users.py
  - tests
     test_users.py
- common
   tests.py
```

My application set up is defined in `application.py`. I'm using the Factory pattern.

```
api = Api(prefix='/api/v0')

def create_app(config_filemane):
  flask_app = Flask(__name__)
  flask_app.config.from_object(config_filemane)
  db.init_app(flask_app)

  from app.users import add_user_resources
  add_user_resources()
  api.init_app(flask_app)

  return flask_app
```

In users.py, I have my Resource subclasses:

```
class UserListAPI(Resource):

  def __init__(self):
    super(UserListAPI, self).__init__()

  def get(self):

  def post(self):


class UserAPI(Resource):

  def __init__(self):
    super(UserAPI, self).__init__()

  def get(self, id):

  def put(self, id):

  def delete(self, id):

def add_user_resources():
  api.add_resource(UserListAPI, '/users', endpoint='users')
  api.add_resource(UserAPI, '/users/<id>', endpoint='user')
```

Please see my [github](https://github.com/ericso/scrying-me) page for the full code.

I set up my unit test class in `common/tests.py` following this [snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/26/).

I run my tests using Nose. When I run any single test, it passes. When I run all tests using

```
$ nosetests
```

I get the following error:

```
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: users
```

I think the error is being caused by the test runner trying to register another Flask-Restful resource after they have already been registered. In users.py, I have two Resource subclasses: `UsersListAPI` and `UsersAPI`. (If you see the github page, I also have the same setup in trips.py.)

I thought that running a single TestCase would not raise the error, because I'm calling `_pre_setup()` in the base case once for the TestCase, where the test app is created but I still get the error if, for instance, I run the test:

```
$ nosetests app.tests.test_users:UsersTest
```

I still get the `AssertionError`.

Any thoughts?

Edit: Here are my test files.

The base test file at common/tests.py:

```
from flask.ext.testing import TestCase
from unittest import TestCase

from application import create_app

class BaseTestCase(TestCase):

    def __call__(self, result=None):
        self._pre_setup()
        super(BaseTestCase, self).__call__(result)
        self._post_teardown()

    def _pre_setup(self):
        self.app = create_app('settings_test')
        self.client = self.app.test_client()
        self._ctx = self.app.test_request_context()
        self._ctx.push()

    def _post_teardown(self):
        self._ctx.pop()
```

Note I'm importing TestCase from both flask.ext.testing and unittest, obviously not both at the same time when actually running the tests. When I import from flask.ext.testcase, the single test fails. Importing from unittest the single test passes:

```
$ nosetests app.tests.test_users:UsersTest.test_get_all_users
```

In both cases, running all tests or just the UsersTest test case, the tests fail. The actual test file, test_users.py is very long. I'll provide it as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/ericso/63c6fec2514b6532b778). I've removed all superfluous code and left only two tests. If you would like to see the full test file, it is at my github [repo](https://github.com/ericso/scrying-me/blob/master/server/app/tests/test_users.py).

Comment: Can you post your test file? What are you doing in the setup/create_app methods of the TestCase?

Comment: I tried running two tests "nosetests --tests=app.tests.test_users:UsersTest.test_get_user_by_username,app.tests.test_users:UsersTest.test_get_all_users". The first test passes and the second fails with the same AssertionError. I really think the test runner is somehow trying to instantiate another copy of the test app.

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/1046, which is very similar to my problem. In this case, however, the issue was the views.py file was being imported twice, resulting in the call to api.add_resource() twice. In my case, I'm wrapping the add_resource calls in a function that is called in create_app.

Comment: If I use unittest.TestCase and run two tests in a single go, the first test passes (no AssertionError) and the second one throws the error. If I use flask.ext.testing.TestCase, the first test will fail because for some reason it tries to create the application twice.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out:

I have to move the line `api = Api(prefix='/api/v0')` into the function `create_app` and moved the `add_resource` functions into `create_app` as well:

```
def create_app(config_filemane):
  flask_app = Flask(__name__)
  ...
  api = Api(prefix='/api/v0')
  api.add_resource(UserListAPI, '/users', endpoint='users')
  api.add_resource(UserAPI, '/users/<id>', endpoint='user')
  ...
  return flask_app
```

The `api` object is no longer global but I don't think I'll need to elsewhere.